# AWS AppSYnc - Access Token vs ID token - Resutls differs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

There is many topics in Access vs ID token and even the protocol documentation says

> ID tokens should never be sent to an API. Access tokens should never be read by the client. [Source](https://oauth.net/id-tokens-vs-access-tokens/)

Now I'm having a very weird and wrong behavior using AppSync, I'm making the use in FE side of the Access Token, everything was working well so far until now. I checked the AppSync console and it was working as expected. The only difference, the console uses the ID token.

The issue is as follow:

```json
query MyQuery {
  Get {
    buildVersion
    distributor
    user {
      userID
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
}

// The resolver is a lambda and returns the following:
{
  "Get": {
    "buildVersion": 42666,
    "distributor": "Company A", // ctx.identity.claims['custom:distributor']
    "user": {
      "userID": "xxxxx-yyyy-zzzzzzzz", // ctx.identity.sub
      "firstName": "Hello",
      "lastName": "World",
    }
  }
}

// Now the AWS AppSync console (with ID token) returns the same object
{
  "data":   {
    "Get": {
      "buildVersion": 42666,
      "distributor": "Company A",
      "user": {
        "userID": "xxxxx-yyyy-zzzzzzzz",
        "firstName": "Hello",
        "lastName": "World",
      }
    }
  }
}

// And the FE (with Access token) has an issue
{
  "data":   {
    "Get": {
      "buildVersion": 42666,
      "distributor": null, // How come this is null???
      "user": {
        "userID": "xxxxx-yyyy-zzzzzzzz",
        "firstName": "Hello",
        "lastName": "World",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My first question is actually **Why this is a thing?** I mean okey, using ID token is not great but why not supporting it. Now **why the results are different?** 
 Extra note, I copied the two request as curl, executed them and got same as browser env. Then I reversed the tokens and this is really tied to the token; the query that was returning null with the Access token is returning the value with the ID token ‍

The lambda is logged before returning, and this weird "filtering" is happening on AppSync side and there is no chaching neither any exotic config

I dont really want to use ID token on my communication FE <> AppSync for the different reason that you can find around, so if there is something I miss, I would be happy to be highlighted on a solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> "distributor": "Company A", // ctx.identity.claims['custom:distributor']

The quid here is it seems that *access_token* can't contain custom claims (it wasn't clear enough in documentation) -though it can contain custom scopes.

So "distributor" will be null in that case.

[About ID tokens](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-id-token.html):

> The ID token can contain OIDC standard claims that are defined in OIDC standard claims. The ID token can also contain custom attributes that you define in your user pool. Amazon Cognito writes custom attribute values to the ID token as strings regardless of attribute type.

One question, why do you need the `distributor` field to be returned in your query if you already have it?

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes I understand it, ID token provides claims so FE can read from it. Here the BE is called with the access token and so the user identified via cognito userpool. Then the lambda resolver is called and the ctx.identity contains the cognito claims from the identified user. The lambda return properly (Can see the plain response in CloudWatch) but the FE do not get the value for some reasons. For the last point that is true, we should probably refactor to use the ID token, but right now it sounds too costly to do this now and in the end the payload should be returned as is.

Comment: Also the other thing that could yield a null value of that field in your response is the mappings. Did the mapping template change?

Comment: No this is what is crazy, I havent found anything, I ended up to use the ID token as AppSync authorization header. That is really insane, the exact same BE nothing is changed, the exact same session, so I login with cognito and get Access, ID and Refresh tokens. Using access one yield null, using ID one returns the attribute ‍ Anyway for the time being use ID token I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The AppSync console uses the **IdToken** while Amplify uses the **AccessToken** by default. This has been confirmed on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4751#issuecomment-613717344).
This causes problems, because the available claims are different between these two tokens.

To still use the AccessToken on the frontend, you can use a **Pre Token Generation Lambda** to add you necessary claims to your AccessToken when it is being generated on the backend. See this great post on Medium for detailed information: [Multi-Tenant AWS Amplify: Method 3: Virtual Cognito Groups](https://medium.com/@dantasfiles/creating-a-simple-multi-tenant-aws-amplify-mobile-app-e26119ab8246)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, now I start to understand what is going on, I will have a deeper look at those resources 